# How to Sort Set<Map<String, Object>> in Java?

Tags: string, sorting, object, dictionary, set

I want to sort Set of type Map, I have already sorted Map recursively, but when it comes to sort Set of Map and I am not able to sort it. I am not able to do so.

I have tried Override Comparator in TreeSet, but that didn't work.

I am getting below error  for `TreeSet<Object> sortedSet = new TreeSet(value)`; line :

TreeSet Cannot sort Set

it gives error message -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable 
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290) 
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538) 
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255) 
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344) 
at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312) 
at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
```

value is Set( Map (String, Object) ), I want to sort and create a JSON object of it.

```
public String getSortCode(Object value) {

  Set<Object> sortedSet = sortSet((Set<Object>) value);
}

private Set<Object> sortSet(Set<Object> value) {

  TreeSet<Object> sortedSet = new TreeSet(value);
  sortedSet.forEach(entry -> {
     if (entry instanceof Map) {
        Map<String, Object> sortedSubMap = sortMap((Map) entry);
        sortedSet.add((Object) sortedSubMap);
     } else if (entry instanceof Set) {
        Set<Object> sortedSubSet = sortSet((Set<Object>) entry);
        sortedSet.add((Object) sortedSubSet);
     }
  });
  return (Set<Object>) sortedSet;
}
```

Thanks in Advance !!
Sushobhit

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - TreeSet Cannot sort Set<Map> it gives error message -"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
 at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
 at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
 at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)"

Comment: Please edit your question and put there the code example or errors.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini - I have put the code take a look.